# Declaration after return statement

Tags: javascript

```
function f() { 
    return f1(); 

    function f1() { 
        return 5; 
    } 
}

f(); // returns 5
```

Why this works? What are benefits of declaration local functions after `return`? Is this good practice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining functions after return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927617/defining-functions-after-return)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works because function declarations are all evaluated on a first pass by the interpreter, so you could place them all at the end of the function if you want, and they will work as though they were at the top.

No benefits. Just a preference. I prefer to have the `return` statement at the end of a function. Seems clearer to me.

Comment: The benefit would be keeping the actual *executing* code together (locality), and not interrupted by a function declaration.