# why userid not change the global userid , it never used userid function declare inside foo

Tags: javascript

I have declared `userid` as a global variable and inside function I have assign a value to `userid` and declared a new function `userid()` but return always before inner function declaration.
Why I'm not able to change the global variable.

```js
var userid = 'test1';

function foo() {
 userid = 'test2';
 return;
 function userid() {}
}

foo();
console.log(userid);
```

It return `test1` however expected result should be `test2`.

If i remove this

```
function userid() {}
```

it works fine.
I know its java script Hoisting played here but why and how?

Comment: Why would you ever write something like this? What's the point of the question?

Comment: I really don't understand why did you defined a function with the same name as the variable and why do you want assign `test2` to `userid` inside of the `foo()` method.

Comment: I also find the question strange, but interesting. if you remove the line "function userid() {} " it will work as expected (the console will display "test2". I have to admit that I do not know why that line after the return is changing the expected behaviour.

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927617/defining-functions-after-return, it explains the "weird" behaviour better than I ever could.

Comment: I Was testing javascript hoisting and find this strange behaviour which i do not understand i have just declare local function not variable with same name.

Comment: @Jon My answer explains the behavior. It's called hoisting. All declarations are hoisted to the top of their enclosing scope, regardless of where they actually appear in the code. This is why the declaration that comes after the return is actually processed first.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, yeah I saw that in the link I added. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, declarations are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) to the top of their enclosing scope, so when you declare the `function id`, it is processed as this:

```
function foo() {
    function userid() {} // Even though you placed this last, it's processed first!
    userid = 'test2';
    return;
}
foo();
console.log(userid);
```

Even though you didn't write the function as the first thing in `foo`, it is processed as if you did and that means that a second `userid` variable is now in the local scope and is "hiding" the global one.

Now, there is still a way to access the global variable and that would be through the global `window` object:

```js
var userid = "something";

function foo() {
  // Hoisting is why we can call functions before we've declared them!
  userid();
  window.userid = 'test2'; // Access the global through the global object
  return;
  // Normally, nothing after a return is processed, but because of 
  // hoisting, this function declaration will be processed first.
  function userid() {
    console.log("hello from userid");
  } 
}
foo();
console.log(userid);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Why does `userid` assignment not change the global `userid` when a `userid()` function is declare inside a `foo()` function?

First, to understand this you need to know that both **function declarations** and **variable declarations** are hoisted to the top of the containing scope (i.e. the top of the function, if is defined in a function, or the top of the global context, if outside a function). Because of this, JavaScript functions can be called before they are declared.

Also, a **function declaration** takes precedence over **variable declarations**, but not over **variable assignments**. Therefore, we can say that a **variable assignment** override a **function declaration**. Remember, JS only hoists declarations, not initializations.

JS `var` statement does not declares a variable in **block-level** scope (variables scoped to surrounding curly brackets). Instead, instead it declares variables in **function-level** scope. This means, variables declared within a function are **local variables** and are only accessible within that function or by functions inside that function.

If you declare a **global variable** and a **local variable** with the same name, the **local variable** will have priority when you attempt to use the variable inside a function (local scope).

Your code is the perfect example, of how a **variable assignment** overrides a **function declaration** in the **local scope** let's analyze it.

```js
var userid = 'test1'; // Variable initialization not hoisted
var bar = 'bar1'; 

function foo() {
  console.log('userid-type: ', typeof userid); // userid() Function declaration hoisted 
  // to the top of the local scope
  userid = 'test2'; // Variable assignment into the local scope that overrides the 
  // function declaration.
  console.log('userid-type: ', typeof userid); // Because, when a variable assigment takes 
  // precedence over function declarations, then the variable is hoisted in the local scope.
  // This is why you got that behaviour.
  
  bar = 'bar2';  // Variable assignment to the global scope.
  return;

  function userid() {}
}

foo();
console.log('userid-value: ', userid);
console.log('bar-value: ', bar);
```

**Why my code does not use the global variable.** Because, the `userid()` **local function** has the same name as the `userid` global variable. Then, when the **variable assignment** occurs  a  `userid` **local variable** exits and belongs to the  `userid()` **local function** then this variable will be override in the local scope because it has priority over the **global variable** .

Comment: *JS does not have block-level scope (variables scoped to surrounding curly brackets) like other languages.* >> Yes, it does if you declare your variable with the `let` keyword.

Comment: I know that `let` and `const` have block-level scope but at the moment of the edition I was thinking about the `var` statement.